# What's the purpose of "instead" here?

Tags: grammar

In *Matrix (1999)*, Boy hands over a spoon to Neo:

> BOY: Do not try and bend the spoon. That's impossible.
> **Instead**, only try to realize the truth.
>
> Neo: What truth?
>
> Boy: There is no spoon.

What's the purpose of "instead" here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be rewritten as

> Bending the spoon is impossible, instead of trying to bend it, try to realize the truth.

Does that help?